# Restrict access to parent directories in PHP

Tags: php, security

I have seen from other questions that I can set `open_basedir` to restrict access to parent folders. However, I decided to do a bit of experimenting to find out what I could do.

First test was to see if I could manually set `open_basedir` using the `ini_set` function. Thankfully, it appears that this function can set a more restrictive basedir, but it cannot be used to lessen the restriction. That's all good.

However my next test was somewhat disturbing:

```
ini_set("open_basedir","/path/to/desired/root/limited");
echo file_get_contents("/some/outsite/file.txt"); // error: basedir restriction
echo `cat /some/outside/file.txt`; // outputs the file
```

I can't seem to find any way to restrict shell access to stuff.

So I guess my real question is, what can I do to ensure that parent folders are safe? Clearly, `open_basedir` doesn't cut it.

Comment: I don't see how `echo 'cat /some/outside/file.txt';` would actually print the file in php. That should physically output `cat /some/outside/file.txt` which doesn't effect open_basedir

Comment: It's unlikely the scope of the shell can be restricted from within PHP. You'd have to restrict the actual user that PHP is running under. You would usually block `exec()` for a completely safe configuration

Comment: @MikeB Backticks. [Learn about 'em](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php)

Comment: Learn something new every day.

Comment: @pekka write your comment as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open_basedir generally doesn't restrict backdoor access like that.  There was a "safe_mode" in PHP which prevented such calls like system() and exec().  Full list here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.functions.php

But that's been deprecated as of PHP 5.3 because there are many ways around it.

You could use suPHP and chroot, as suggested by another StackOverflow answer: [PHP safemode alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892657/php-safemode-alternative)

"A better approach is use suphp to run your application as a jailed user. This uses the security of the operating system to protect your application. You run your php code as an account that doesn't have access to a shell. You remove write privileges from everything owned by that user chmod 500 -R /. Or go a step further and run your application within a chroot."

Useful links:

- http://www.suphp.org/Home.html
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot
- http://www.fuschlberger.net/programs/ssh-scp-sftp-chroot-jail/make_chroot_jail.sh

Answer (score 0):

Well, i doubt you cant even achieve that within single CPANEL/account.
its a horror (you have to set `open_basedir`,`allowOverride`,`safe_mode` and even other restrictions are needed for cgi/perl/cron-jobs...

you'd better to use Reseller(WHM) Cpanel account, or DirectAdmin(cpanel alternative) Multi-user accounts.